# Processing Array of Objects Not Initialized

Tags: arrays, object, processing

I'm just trying to fill an Object array with Objects using a for loop but for some reason it only fills the first index, all other indices of the array remain null. I've tried referencing [other Processing code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66193449/array-of-objects-returns-null) which does the same thing, and as far as I can tell my code matches? Maybe it's just a small error I'm missing but it has evaded me for like an hour x-x

Here's my Main class:

```
GalleryRoom[] rooms = new GalleryRoom[12];
int frameCount = 10;

void setup() {
   for(int i = 0; i<rooms.length;i++) {
   rooms[i] = new GalleryRoom();
   rooms[i].setGallery("Prefix", frameCount, i);
   print(rooms[0].getCount());
  }
}
```

Printing the getCount method for object 0 of rooms array gives `4111111111116` after iterating through the entire for loop, printing any other object gives NPE.

And my GalleryRoom Object class:

```
PImage[] images;
int imageCount;

public class GalleryRoom {
  public void setGallery(String imagePrefix, int count, int x) {
    imageCount = count;
    images = new PImage[imageCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < imageCount; i++) {
      String filename = "Folder"+x+"/"+imagePrefix + nf(i, 4) + ".gif";
      images[i] = loadImage(filename);
    } 
  }
  public int getCount() {
    return imageCount;
  }
}
```

Comment: Language tag?  Is this Java or C#?  (Your referenced question refers to Java.)

Comment: Processing is a java based language: https://processing.org

Answer (score 0):

I really urge You to define the state of the Object **inside the body of the Class**:

```java
public class GalleryRoom {
  PImage[] images;
  int imageCount;
  
  GalleryRoom(String imagePrefix, int count, int x) {
    this.imageCount = count;
    this.images = new PImage[imageCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < imageCount; i++) {
      String filename = "Folder"+x+"/"+imagePrefix + nf(i, 4) + ".gif";
      //images[i] = loadImage(filename);
      println(filename);
    }
  }
  public int getCount() {
    return this.imageCount;
  }
}
```

Now, You can call *new GalleryRoom*:

```java
GalleryRoom[] rooms = new GalleryRoom[12];
int frameCount = 10;

void setup() {
  for (int i = 0; i<rooms.length; i++) {
    rooms[i] = new GalleryRoom("Prefix", frameCount, i);
    println(rooms[0].getCount());
  }
}
```

Just a friendly reminder that It's a convention to use a constructor with parameters instead of a method that configures the created object.